# How to indicate someone's spirits are very gentle

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Please imagine an emotional man / woman who's morale is like a child and even sometimes seems to to be a bit sensitive. Which one of the following adjectives can indicate such a message that the man in our question has such nice and delicate spirits:

- He has a very..........morale.

> - a) gentle
> - b) delicate
> - c) tender

I hope I could make myself understood. However, this is a direct translation from my language to English. If you got my point, and think that there is a better / more common way to convey the same message, then I would appreciate it if you let me know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of idioms that express this in English,for example:

> He is a gentle person.
>
> He is emotional.
>
> He is easily moved.
>
> He is sensitive / He has a sensitive nature.
>
> He cares deeply (about things) / He is a caring person

*Morale* does not work here, as it means something quite different:

> [Morale](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/morale): 1. *the mental and emotional condition (as of enthusiasm, confidence, or loyalty) of an individual or group with regard to the function or tasks at hand*, 2. *the level of individual psychological well-being based on such factors as a sense of purpose and confidence in the future*

"Nature" or "spirit" or (in some cases) "demeanor" is a more appropriate word.

"Delicate" is close, but it's normally used to imply the person is either *fragile* (easily broken) or, depending on context, something of an [*epicure*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/epicure) (has very particular tastes).

> Please walk quietly around Fred, his delicate nature makes him jump at loud noises.
>
> Fred has delicate sensibilities, especially with wine.  He only likes the best Bordeaux vintages.

Comment: Hence, your first offer works the best for me. What do you think of it @Andrew? Do you confirm that the closest and the most neutral choice would be the first offer of yours?

Comment: @A-friend  It depends on what you want to say.  A more poetic way to express this is "He is a gentle spirit."  Of course if you really want to be poetic you can dive into analogy, imagery, and metaphor.

Answer (score 2):

I think "delicate" is the best adjective of the three, but I don't like the resulting phrase: *delicate morale*.

I think *self-esteem* might work better than *morale* for the situation you describe. It seems *morale* would be a better word to describe the overall mood of a group, whereas *self-esteem* focuses more on an individual's feelings.

Comment: How about spirits @J.R.? Doesn't is sound better than "morale" here when I say: **"He has very delicate spirits"**?